# How can I save an encrypted data using Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey() in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

This is the model.

```
public function genCode($width = 15)
{   
    $inputKey = $this->password();
    $string = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString($width);
    $this->_encrypted = Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey( $string, $inputKey );
    // $decrypted = Yii::$app->security->decryptByKey( $encrypted, $inputKey, $info = null );
    return $this->_encrypted;
}

public function saveCodeSample()
{
    $code = new Code;
    $code->type = 'sample';
    $code->owner_id = 1;
    $code->value = $this->genCode();
    return $code->save();
}

private function password()
{
    $inputKey = 'averyrandomandverylongstring';
    $this->_password = $inputKey;

    return $this->_password;
}
```

This is the controller sample

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $codes = new CodesSetup;
    return var_dump($codes->saveCodeSample());
}
```

This doesn't give me any error but the PROBLEM is, all data is saved into the database except the encrypted one.

Model Rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['type', 'owner_id', 'code'], 'required'],
        [['owner_id', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'author_id', 'updater_id'], 'integer'],
        [['type', 'code'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}
```

Comment: If that is the whole of your model then it's not saving, probably because you haven't specified any data validation

Comment: Show in `Code` class method `rules()`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added the rules from my Code model. Just to make it clear, I have no problem saving any data to the database, it's just that when it is Encrypted, it is either blank or around 2 random characters on the code column.

Comment: Use `echo` to print the encrypted value and exit immediately to see what it is encrypting it to and verify the encryption is working.

Comment: @Chloe if you check the Test route, it returns a var_dump of the encrypted code. This is not the issue since it is encrypted properly. The data saved in the database is the problem.

Comment: Show us your database schema for that table. Show us the model for `Codes`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try utf8_encode before saving, issue occurs because of database fields encoding.

```
$this->_encrypted = utf8_encode(Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey( $string, $inputKey ));
```

Comment: Hmmhm, Looks like this is the solution. I'll test it soon.

Comment: I'm using the same in beforeSave method but is save empty into database and when I use die after $model->save() it'll save into database. How can save encrypted value into DB.

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same problem and utf8_encode/utf8_decode worked for me

```
$encrypted = utf8_encode(Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey($data, $key));
$decrypted = Yii::$app->security->decryptByKey(utf8_decode($encrypted), $key);
```

Comment: I'm using the same in beforeSave method but is save empty into database and when I use die after $model->save() it'll save into database. How can save encrypted value into DB